# How to use custom language highlight syntax in Gtk SourceView?

Tags: gtk, gtk3, gtksourceview

I'm trying to create my own language definition, and use it for highlighting the syntax in my app.

The issue I have is that, when trying to access the language definition from my app's data folder (`/usr/share/myapp/`), even using the `c.lang` file copied from `/usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/`, just to test, I get this error at runtime:

```
GtkSourceView-WARNING **: Failed to load '/usr/share/myapp/c.lang': could not find the RelaxNG schema file
```

So it's asking for some schema file? So I went forward and copied every file from the `language-specs` folder that isn't a `lang` file, which includes: `language.dtd`, `language.rng` and `language2.rng`.

Now, when I run again, I get these errors:

```
GtkSourceView-WARNING **: in file /usr/share/com.github.aleksandar-stefanovic.urmsimulator/c.lang: style 'def:comment' not defined

GtkSourceView-WARNING **: Failed to load '/usr/share/com.github.aleksandar-stefanovic.urmsimulator/c.lang': unable to resolve language 'def'
```

What does that even mean? Is that something namespace-related? It is very peculiar, because the exact same file is working perfectly when in `gtksourceview` folder.

Any clues? Do these "RelaxNG" files work only in their original directories? If so, how can I change that? I've looked into the files, but failed to find any reference to their original folder...

This is the source-code (in Vala) related to the issue:

```
var manager = Gtk.SourceLanguageManager.get_default ();
string search_paths[] = {"/usr/share/myapp", null};
manager.set_search_path (search_paths);
var buffer = new Gtk.SourceBuffer.with_language (manager.get_language ("c"));
```

The application does in fact find the language "c", I've checked by debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to preserve the `Gtk.SourceLanguageManager`'s original search path when you add your own. Append to it instead of replacing it.